# How do I grab an index from an array in a HashMap?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I've got a `HashMap<Object, String[]>` I just want to grab the 0 index position from the `String[]`. How do I do that?

Can I just do this? `mMap.get(position)[0]`?

Comment: Where is the problem in simply trying this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you've indicated, provided `position` is a key in the map.

Comment: +1, for understanding the question and providing the correct response that yes, it is valid as long as `position` is a key.

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap` doesn't have a `0`index and it doesn't have a `String[]`

You cannot do what you ask because it doesn't make sense.

> Can I just do this? mMap.get(position)[0]?

You can. Have you tried this to see if it works?  Note: it will fail if map.get() returns null

Comment: I'm saying i want to get the 0 index postion of the String[] at whatever position in the HashMap..

Comment: You can call a variable "position" but HashMap doesn't have positions it has keys and values. Otherwise you should be able to answer your own question by trying it.

Answer (score 2):

A map is not an array.  It's a dictionary of keys that map to items.  So there is no ordered index in the Map part, there's a lookup key.  This means that a Map has no "next" item.

In the event that you stored a String[] in the map, then you could get the first element of the String array like so:

```
String first = ((String[])mMap.get(lookupKey))[0];
```

Since you are using generics, your compiler will make the casting unnecessary, simplifying the answer to

```
String first = mMap.get(lookupKey)[0];
```

Note that this is not using the position to access the item stored in the Map, it's using the lookup key.  In addition, there is a casting of the returned Object into a String[] (because we stored a String[] in the map earlier), and then there is a dereferncing of the first ('0') element.

Comment: @mre, depends on the version of Java.  Pre-generics, yes there was a need to cast.  However, the poster just edited the question to include the type of the map which now has generics.  Or if he didn't edit it, I need more coffee because I missed it.

Comment: No, your coffee level's fine, the OP clarified it within the edit window. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little demo program that does what you're asking.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FirstElementInHashMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Object,String[]> mMap = new HashMap<Object,String[]>();
        mMap.put("myKeyA", new String[] { "myValue1", "myValue2", "myValue3" });
        mMap.put("myKeyB", new String[] { "myValue4", "myValue5", "myValue6" });
        mMap.put("myKeyC", new String[] { "myValue7", "myValue8", "myValue9" });

        Object position = "myKeyB";
        String[] strings = mMap.get(position);

        // make sure position exists in the Map and contains a non-empty array
        // so we don't throw an NullPointerException
        String firstStringInArray = null;
        if (strings != null && strings.length > 0) {
            firstStringInArray = strings[0];
        }
        System.out.println(firstStringInArray);
    }
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
myValue4
```